# Fiddle not working in new jQuery

Tags: jquery, version, jsfiddle

I made a fiddle with old jQuery but my website use a new jQuery, and I don't know how to make the code work again. Here you are:

- working: http://jsfiddle.net/hThGb/3626/
- not working: http://jsfiddle.net/hThGb/3627/

HTML

```
<div id="button"><button>toggle</button></div>
<div id="zelena"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#button').toggle(
    function() {
        $('#zelena').animate({right: -200})
    }, function() {
        $('#zelena').animate({right: 0})
})
```

CSS

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
}

#zelena {
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
width: 200px;
background:green;
position: absolute;
}
#button {
left: 0px;
position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toggle event was deprecated and eventually removed. However, someone wrote [**a small plugin**](https://github.com/maniator/jQuery-toggleClick) that can do the same thing the `toggle` event did. However, you really do not need the plugin in your case; a few lines should do it:

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    var zln = $('#zelena'),
        right = +zln.css("right").replace(/px/i, '');
    right = right === 0 ? -200 : 0;
    zln.animate({right: right})
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hThGb/3631/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $('#zelena').stop().animate({
            right: -200
        });
    } else {
        $('#zelena').stop().animate({
            right: 0
        });
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/hThGb/3629/)